# Get Integer value from NSNumber in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, iterator, nsarray, nsnumber

I have an NSArray with NSNumber objects that have int values:

```
arrayOfValues = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:3], [NSNumber numberWithInt:5], [NSNumber numberWithInt:6], [NSNumber numberWithInt:7], nil] autorelease];
[arrayOfValues retain];
```

I'm trying to iterate through the array like this:

```
int currentValue;
for (int i = 0; i < [arrayOfValues count]; i++)
{
    currentValue = [(NSNumber *)[arrayOfValues objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
    NSLog(@"currentValue: %@", currentValue); // EXE_BAD_ACCESS
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are using the wrong format specifier. %@ is for objects, but int is not an object. So, you should be doing this:

```
int currentValue;
for (int i = 0; i < [arrayOfValues count]; i++)
{
    currentValue = [(NSNumber *)[arrayOfValues objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
    NSLog(@"currentValue: %d", currentValue); // EXE_BAD_ACCESS
}
```

More information [in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).

Comment: I thought %@ was a wild card so I could pass anything

Comment: You can pass any object, but like I said, int is not an object.

Comment: thanks, this does help with clarification and the error. having a DOH! (slap hand on head) moment

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me when creating an NSArray of enum values I wanted to call (which is useful to know that this is the proper solution for that) I'm using Xcode 6.4.

```
int currentValue = (int)[(NSNumber *)[arrayOfValues objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];
```

sosborn's answer will throw a warning since it is still necessary to cast the NSInteger to an int.

Typecasting in ObjC is the bane of my existence.  I hope this helps someone!